# Resolving mapreduce.Cluster Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider due to error in instantiating YarnClient

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, redhat, bigdata

I have setup a basic Hadoop 2.6.0 + Hive 0.14.0 on a test single node cluster mainly following these guides:

Hadoop:
http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/

Hive:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

If I run the WordCount java example however, I get this error:

```
$ hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/hadoop/HDFSClient.java /user/hadoop/wc.out
16/02/08 12:24:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/02/08 12:24:56 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/02/08 12:24:56 INFO mapreduce.Cluster: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider due to error: Error in instantiating YarnClient
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1262)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
        at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

The conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
      </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
      </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:8000</value>
      </property>

</configuration>
```

The conf/yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
        </property>

 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
     <value>0.0.0.0:8004</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

The conf/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
      <value>50031</value>
   </property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

I am a bit new to setting up Hadoop and Hive and would appreciate any advise or pointers on possible things to look at.

Comment: check your yarn-site.xml property...it should be `mapreduce_shuffle`

Answer (score 1):

replace your core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml and yarn-site.xml file properties with following

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapre-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but it didn't work. I've restarted via start/stop-yarn/dfs.sh.  I still get the same error when running WordCount example.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses` as your log file..mapred-site.xml file parameter is wrong..check with above mentioned parameters and once again format your namenode with updated parameters and start your daemons..

Comment: I have done the reformat. That seems to have helped things. But I am still stuck at the same error. I have done a grep of WARN|ERROR in hadoop/logs/*.log and cannot see anything that indicates a red flag, so still scratching my head.

Comment: if I have yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle in yarn-site that gives this warning: `961 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: The Auxilurary Service named 'mapreduce_shuffle' in the configuration is for class class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler which has a name of 'httpshuffle'. Because these are not the same tools trying to send ServiceData and read Service Meta Data may have issues unless the refer to the name in the config.`

Comment: come to chat we will discuss there

Comment: hadoop room in chat:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/102948/hadoop?tab=general.  Also on email dnr1@yahoogroups.com or https://www.facebook.com/groups/hadoop20/

Comment: Solving it in chat does not help me, now that I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to work if you run you application with 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar' in you classpath.